# Does LTE Band 20 (800) really matter?

Tags: rom, xiaomi, 4g

I'm looking to import Redmi K30 Ultra, and since it is not available globally (only Chinese ROM), in the specs it is stated it does not support LTE B20(800). My operator provides following coverage:

4G -> B3(1800) and B20(800)

3G -> B1(2100) and B8(900)

2G -> B3(1800) and B8(900)

All other bands are supported by the mentioned device.

Now, I have some basic understanding about the topic, such as, lower frequencies means broader coverage but lower speeds and vice versa.
But I am wondering if someone could tell me will I really notice the lack of B20 (e.g. will device be prone to losing 4G connection and going to 3G often). Are there any experiences regarding this problem (not necessarily with this phone). Thanks!

Comment: You're not really giving us much to go one... Does your phone need to cover every single band your carrier has? Maybe, this depends where you live and who your carrier is. For example, in the US AT&T has LTE on bands 2, 4, 5, 12, 14, 17, 29, 30, and 66, but half of those are only in very limited areas of high congestion, and if you phone supports 2, 4, 5, 12, and 17 there probably isn't anywhere in the country you wouldn't have service that bands 14, 29, 30, or 66 would have coverage. Does your carrier use B3 as their primary and B20 as their backup, or is it distributed? Need more info...

Comment: B20 at 800MHz is usually used outside of cities were the mobile cells cover a larger area (because 800MHz is good for "long-ranged" connections). Therefore I would expect that inside cities you won't face any problem but in rural area you will most likely get no LTE connection. If 3G is still active in that area your phone will drop to 3G but note that in a lot of countries mobile network operators start to disable 3G networks or at least decreasing the number of cell phone towers that use 3G.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I will contact my carrier and now I know which question I need to ask. I live in the city, but I don't want to lose connection when I travel somewhere, especially if they are removing 3G towers. Thanks again, information you provided is very useful to me.